# Working on a timer for my text-based rpg on input

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a timer for my text-based RPG. I would like it set up so that if a user doesn't input something within a given time the program will exit with a message.

I have tried different import to complete this, but every time it's had an issue with implementing an outside timer function in the functions I've already created. The best I could come up with is letting it run, but the user can still input things and continue with the game.

```py
from threading import Timer


def Timed():
    timeout = 5
    t = Timer(timeout, print, ['The guards catch you. They execute you on the spot.. You die.'])
    t.start()
    
def escape_scene():
    Timed()
    decisions = ["left", "right", "up"]
    print("You walk into an opening filled with guards! Where do you go?")
    answer = ""
    while answer not in decisions:
        print("Options: left/right/up")
        answer = input()
        if answer == "left":
            nothing()
        elif answer == "right":
            nothing()
        elif answer == "up":
            example()
        else:
            print("That is not an option.")
            escape_scene()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the command-line solution but maybe you can consider using [pyxel](https://github.com/kitao/pyxel) which gives you more options and flexibility. For example here is the timer implementation:

```
import time
import pyxel


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        pyxel.init(250, 150, display_scale=3, title='Viul\'s RPG')
        self.timer = True
        self.start = time.time()
        self.time_left = None
        pyxel.run(self.update, self.draw)

    def update(self):
        self.time_left = 5 - int(time.time()-self.start)
        if self.time_left >= 0 and (pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_LEFT) or pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_RIGHT) or pyxel.btn(pyxel.KEY_UP)):
            self.timer = False

    def draw(self):
        pyxel.cls(pyxel.COLOR_BLACK)
        if self.timer and self.time_left >= 0:
            pyxel.text(x=1, y=1, s='You walk into an opening filled with guards! Where do you go?', col=pyxel.COLOR_WHITE)
            pyxel.text(x=1, y=10, s='Options:', col=pyxel.COLOR_WHITE)
            pyxel.text(x=35, y=10, s='Left, Right, Up', col=pyxel.COLOR_GREEN)
            pyxel.text(x=1, y=20, s='Time left:', col=pyxel.COLOR_WHITE)
            pyxel.text(x=45, y=20, s=str(self.time_left), col=pyxel.COLOR_RED)
        elif self.timer and self.time_left < 0:
            pyxel.text(x=1, y=1, s='The guards catch you. They execute you on the spot.. You die.', col=pyxel.COLOR_WHITE)
        elif not self.timer:
            pyxel.text(x=1, y=1, s='You run away from them as fast as you can...', col=pyxel.COLOR_WHITE)


App()
```

Output:

[image: RPG]

Comment: Hey, I've played with this example for a bit. I'm trying to figure out a way to reset the timer itself. In the original game, I would transition from one scene to another. To do this the timer would also need to be reset each time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Viul that's the separate topic. Please create another question about transition between scenes and I'll help you with a pleasure.